# How to make work soft deletable and unique entity using symfony 2

Tags: symfony, unique, soft-delete

I've soft deletable and a uniqueentity field. It works great but...

If the record is deleted "softdeleted", I can't create the same record. I think it's because the record is not realy deleted in the DB. But I need to that.

So what is the best way to dothis ?

1. Totaly deleted the record ? So is softdeletable a good choice ?
2. Find a way that if the record is softdeleted, I can create again the same record

Thanks for your advices

Answer (score 6):

After you removed the unique constraint from the database level, You can set to your entity this.

```
@UniqueEntity(fields={"name", "deleteTime"}, ignoreNull=false)
```

In this case the validation will fail if you already have a "non-soft deleted" row with the given name in your database, but it won't if the deleteTime is setted.

Comment: I guess this works only if the "name" field has a NotBlank constraint?

Comment: You are right. There is only one null value allowed. From the documentation: "ignoreNull: If set to false, only one null value is allowed"
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#ignorenull

Answer (score 2):

You have three choices

- Hard Delete the item
- Remove the Unique (and handle it in doctrine)
- When you create the new entity, you deactivate the softdeletable filter

  $em->getFilters()->disable('soft-deleteable');

This will let you find the "deleted" items. Then you can do things like overwrite the old entry, harddelete it manually or whatever your app needs you to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

since you are using soft delete and unique constraints, you can't actually use a unique constraint on the database level.

I suggest you handle the unique constraint check manually, this could be done in a [doctrine life cycle event](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#prepersist)

One way to do this is by creating a callback function in your entity and annotate it to fire on the event:

```
/** @PrePersist */
public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getObject();
    $entityManager = $args->getObjectManager();

    // check if this entity's unique field is OK
}
```

This will only ensure you don't save anything incorrect in the database, but it won't handle your forms nicely. So in addition, you probably want to use the [`UniqueEntity` validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) for this, and create a custom `repositoryMethod` to check the uniqueness.

This custom repository method can be used by both the `prePersist` and the `UniqueEntity` validator.

Comment: Your idea to use another ``repositoryMethod`` is great! Do you have an example? It should be added to the DoctrineExtensions documentation.

Comment: It's available in the [validator's documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#repositorymethod) :)

Comment: But how do I change it in such a way that it ignores soft-deleted entities while looking for duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I used this way

1. Remove the unique index of the column on the Database

   ```
    public function up(Schema $schema) : void
     {  
          $this->addSql('DROP INDEX UNIQ_A2E0150FE7927C74 ON admins');
           $this->addSql('CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_A2E0150FE7927333 ON 
      admins (email,deleted_at)');
   ```

   }
2. Add this constraint on your Entity

   ```
   /**
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=AdminRepository::class)
     * @ORM\Table(name="admins",
     *    uniqueConstraints={
     *        @UniqueConstraint(name="admins",
     *            columns={"email", "deleted_at"})
     * })
   ```

It means that you make the pair `email` (unique column) and `deleted_at` unique, instead of just the `email` field. And now, I can create another admin with the same `email`, if the old one was deleted (Using soft delete)